# JavaScript class with mongoose db

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I want to use a class (with name `Paste`) with the following methods:
`Paste.create()` - Creates a new record in MongoDB using mongoose.
`Paste.find()` - Finds a record in MongoDB using mongoose.

This is my Paste.js:

```js
const db = require("../models/schema");

class Paste {
    constructor( id, content, title, description, language ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.language = language;
    }


    create() {
        db.create({
            id: this.id,
            content: this.content,
            title: this.title,
            description: this.description,
            language: this.language
         })
    }


    find(id) {
        const r = db.findOne({ id: id });
        if(r==undefined) return false;
        return {
            id: r.id,
            content: r.content,
            title: r.title,
            description: r.description,
            language: r.language
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Paste;
```

And this is the code I'm using to use those methods: (it executes when a HTML button is clicked)

```js
const { MONGO_URI } = require("../config.json");
const { generateKey } = await import('crypto');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Paste = require("./classes/Paste");

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

registerPaste = () => {
    try {

        let title = null;
        if(document.getElementById("pasteTitle").value > 20) {
        title = document.getElementById("pasteTitle").value.slice(0, 40) + `...`
        }

        let id = null;
        generateKey("aes", { length: 10 }, (err, key) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            id = key.export().toString("hex");
          })
        
        const p = new Paste(id, document.getElementById("pasteContent").value, document.getElementById("pasteTitle").value, document.getElementById("pasteDescrp").value, document.getElementById("pasteLang").value);
        p.create();
        window.location.replace(`${window.location.href}/${id}`);
    } 
    catch {
        console.error;
    }
}
```

The html code for calling the `registerPaste()` function:

```html
  <button class="btn no-animation btn-success font-p create-btn" onclick="registerPaste()">Create paste</button>
```

**When the button is clicked, it does not redirect to the URL of the newly created paste...Hope someone helps!**

#### More details:

- Node.JS version: 16.8.0
- I'm using expressjs to render the static HTML, CSS files.

Comment: ... just wonder, how the code `document.getElementById("pasteContent").value` - should work on the server-side (node.js has no document and any of its props) ... ? :\

Comment: Oh, sorry I wasn't aware of that, do you know any other way of getting values from an input in Node.JS?

Comment: well, read the basics (client-server interaction ) - your client app can make Xhr (for example) requests to the server-side (with HTTP requests (aka GET, POST, PUT....) and send ie. json (or form-) data to the server-side code (node.js controllers / endpoints) and so on ... check the sample repo (for example) : http://github.com/VovanSuper/MERN-dummy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect the html frontend to an express backend with no network call. In addition you are mixing frontend and backend code together trying to access DOM elements from within the node server. You'll need to use an ajax call of some kind. Jquery (ajax) would work here, as well as Axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios. Otherwise there is no way for the on-click to access your server.

You will also need to setup routes. I would recommend spending some time looking at the express documentation. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html and maybe watching some express server tutorials to get a better idea of how to connect the front and backend.